# How to use the tf.case api of TensorFlow correctly?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to design a follow function for expanding any `1D/2D/3D` matrix to a `4D` matrix.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def inputs_2_4D(inputs):
    _ranks = tf.rank(inputs)
    return tf.case({tf.equal(_ranks, 3): lambda: tf.expand_dims(inputs, 3),
                    tf.equal(_ranks, 2): lambda: tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(inputs, 0), 3),
                    tf.equal(_ranks, 1): lambda: tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(inputs, 0), 0), 3)},
                    default=lambda: tf.identity(inputs))

def run():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
       mat_1d = tf.constant([1, 1])
       mat_2d = tf.constant([[1, 1]])
       mat_3d = tf.constant([[[1, 1]]])
       mat_4d = tf.constant([[[[1, 1]]]])

       result = inputs_2_4D(mat_1d)
       print(result.eval())
```

The function, however, cannot run well. It can only perform to output a `4-D` matrix when the `mat_3d` and `mat-4d` tensors are passed into it. There will be some errors information if a `1D` or `2D` matrix are passed to the function.

When passing `mat_3d`or`mat_4d`into `inputs_2_4D()`, they can be expanded to a 4D matrix or original matrix:

```
     mat_3d -----> [[[[1]
                      [1]]]]
     mat_4d -----> [[[[1 1]]]]
```

When `mat_1d`or`mat_2d`matrixes are passed into `inputs_2_4D`, error information:

```
ValueError: dim 3 not in the interval [-2, 1]. for 'case/cond/ExpandDims' (op: 'ExpandDims') with input shapes: [2], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <3>.
```

I tested another similar function before. That function can run correctly.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def test_2_4D(inputs):
    _ranks = tf.rank(inputs)
     return tf.case({tf.equal(_ranks, 3): lambda: tf.constant(3),
                     tf.equal(_ranks, 2): lambda: tf.constant(2),
                     tf.equal(_ranks, 1): lambda: tf.constant(1)},
                     default=lambda: tf.identity(inputs))

def run():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      mat_1d = tf.constant([1, 1])
      mat_2d = tf.constant([[1, 1]])
      mat_3d = tf.constant([[[1, 1]]])
      mat_4d = tf.constant([[[[1, 1]]]])

      result = test_2_4D(mat_3d)
      print(result.eval())
```

This function can correctly output the corresponding results when passing all of matrixes.

`test_2_4D()` RESULTS:

```
    mat_1d -----> 1
    mat_2d -----> 2
    mat_3d -----> 3
    mat_4d -----> [[[[1 1]]]]
```

I don't know why the correct branch in `inputs_2_4D()` cannot be found while the `tf.equal()` in each branch were executed. I feel that the 1st and 2nd branches in the function seem to still work if the input matrix is `"mat_1d"` or `"mat_2d".` So, the program will crash down. Please help me to analyze this problem!

Comment: Please post an example of the errors you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I worked out what the problem is here. Turns out all condition/function pairs are evaluated. This can be revealed by giving the ops different names. The problem is that if your input is, say, rank 2, Tensorflow seems to still evaluate `tf.equal(_ranks, 3): lambda: tf.expand_dims(inputs, 3)`. This leads to a crash because it cannot expand dim 3 for a rank-2 tensor (the maximum allowed value is 2).

This actually makes sense since with `tf.case` you're basically saying "I don't know which of these cases is going to be true at runtime, so check which one is appropriate and execute the corresponding function". However this means that Tensorflow needs to prepare execution paths for *all* possible cases, which in this case leads to invalid computations (trying to expand invalid dimensions).

At this point it would be nice to know a little more about your problem, i.e. why exactly you need that function. If you have different inputs and you simply want to bring them all to 4D, but each input always has the same dimensionality, consider simply using Python if-statements. Example:

```
inputs3d = tf.constant([[[1,1]]])  # this is always 3D
inputs2d = tf.constant([[1,1]])  # this is alwayas 2D
...

def inputs_2_4D(inputs):
    _rank = len(inputs.shape.as_list())
    if _rank == 3:
        return tf.expand_dims(inputs, 3)
    elif _rank == 2:
        return tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(inputs, 0), 3)
    ...
```

This will check the input rank while the graph is being built (not *at runtime* like `tf.case`) and really only prepare those `expand_dims` ops that are appropriate for the given input.

However if you have a single `inputs` tensor and this could have different ranks at different times of your program this would require a different solution. Please let us know which problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: Your idea is nice! I can check it. Keep touch!

Comment: I edited my answer since it didn't work. It now uses the length of the static shape of the input tensor instead of `tf.rank`.  
In the future, please use comments to make, well, comments, instead of posting as an answer.

Comment: Hi, @xdurch0. I have implemented the functionality by `tf.cond` api. But I have not yet any idea to use `tf.case`.

Answer (score 0):

I have implement the functionality I want through 2 ways. Now, I provide my code to share.

The 1st method based on `tf.cond`:

```
def inputs_2_4D(inputs):
    _rank1d = tf.rank(inputs)
    def _1d_2_2d(): return tf.expand_dims(inputs, 0)
    def _greater_than_1d(): return tf.identity(inputs)
    _tmp_2d = tf.cond(_rank1d < 2, _1d_2_2d, _greater_than_1d)

    _rank2d = tf.rank(_tmp_2d)
    def _2d_2_3d(): return tf.expand_dims(_tmp_2d, 0)
    def _greater_than_2d(): return tf.identity(_tmp_2d)
    _tmp_3d = tf.cond(_rank2d < 3, _2d_2_3d, _greater_than_2d)

    _rank3d = tf.rank(_tmp_3d)
    def _3d_2_4d(): return tf.expand_dims(_tmp_3d, 3)
    def _greater_than_3d(): return tf.identity(_tmp_3d)

    return (tf.cond(_rank3d < 4, _3d_2_4d, _greater_than_3d))
```

The 2nd method based on `tf.case` with `tf.cond`:

```
def inputs_2_4D_1(inputs):
    _rank = tf.rank(inputs)
    def _assign_original(): return tf.identity(inputs)
    def _dummy(): return tf.expand_dims(inputs, 0)

    _1d = tf.cond(tf.equal(_rank, 1), _assign_original, _dummy)
    _2d = tf.cond(tf.equal(_rank, 2), _assign_original, _dummy)
    _3d = tf.cond(tf.equal(_rank, 3), _assign_original, _dummy)

    def _1d_2_4d(): return tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(_1d, 0), 0), 3)
    def _2d_2_4d(): return tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(_2d, 0), 3)
    def _3d_2_4d(): return tf.expand_dims(_3d, 3)

    return (tf.case({tf.equal(_rank, 1): _1d_2_4d,
                     tf.equal(_rank, 2): _2d_2_4d,
                     tf.equal(_rank, 3): _3d_2_4d},
                     default=_assign_original))
```

I think the efficiency of the 2nd method should be less than the 1st method's, because the function `_dummy()` always wastes 2 operations when allocating `inputs` into `_1d`,`_2d`,`_3d` respectively.